# How can I avoid rakk attacks?

Tags: borderlands-2

Rakk, those bat-like things that serve pain from above, seem to have attacks that are impossible to avoid.  Even if I jump at the last second, they still end up somehow scoring a hit on me.  Is there a way to dodge their attacks?

Comment: Are you _strictly_ interested in dodging or are ways of killing the rakks before they hit you good too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are playing Borderlands 2, not Hitman: Absolution, last I checked.  Nothing in Borderlands 2 should scream STEALTH, rather, it should scream, SHOOT!

Shotguns work great against rakk, as the spread of the pellets allows for almost insta-kills at close range.  Trying to use weapons that have higher spreads should allow you to shred through rakk quickly.  Avoid using snipers or rocket launchers; rakk move fast, and can easily dodge your attacks.

That said, if you really want to dodge a rakk attack, try strafing to the side and jumping.  That usually makes them miss.

Comment: On the "attack is best defense" side of things, if you're the Commando, the turret is a blessing against those things.

Comment: @leokhorn Deathtrap (from Gaige) makes short work of just about anything in the air as well.

Comment: Sniper rifles are just as good as anything to kill rakks. They fly in a straight line at you, so they're impossible to miss.

Answer (score 5):

Rakk always attack in  a straight line. Pay attention to the mini-map to see where they are in relation to you, then rotate to face their attack. Any rapid-firing weapon should be sufficient to take them down. I've successfully used shotguns, assault rifles, and pistols (both repeaters and revolvers).  A well-timed melee attack will also take them down.

If none of these work, you can always equip a shield that provides elemental damage (such as a [Maliwan Spike shield](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Spike_Shield)). When the rakk hits you, it takes damage, and usually enough to kill it.

Answer (score 4):

Equip a spike shield which damages all melee attackers, and the Rakks will kill themself when they attack you. Rakks have quite low HP, so when you have a good shield and they aren't too high-level, their first attack will be their last one.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you actually want to *avoid* them...

In general order of priority...

- Some rakk flocks are just hanging around, especially early on. If you don't shoot at them, they won't attack. (Later-game flocks seem to be a lot more aggressive though.)

And that's roughly the limit of how to not poke the bear, so to speak. Next up is "how not to get hit while killing them".

- if you can get to somewhere with overhead cover, that will often prevent them from getting an attack run in.
- Less effective but still useful is to get against a wall - not only does it prevent the attacks from that side, the rakks tend to get hung up on the wall trying to finish their swoop, which makes them easy targets.
- If you're in open space, getting a vehicle makes life easier (both because you have infinite ammo and a bigger stack of health). I'd recommend the machine gun turret.

In all those cases (and the worst-case "stuck in the open with no vehicle"), you want a shotgun, SMG, or assault rifle, watch your minimap to see where they're coming from, and pour fire downrange. Rakks attack straight-line and don't have huge health bars, so it's fairly easy to drop one.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy that works best for me is to run backwards while aiming to the entire flock. They tend to fly in a line so you'll have a good angle to shoot one after another as they fall.

Some rapid fire weapon (i.e. any good Vladof gun) should dispose of them easily. If they get close, switch to a shotgun. Rather than dodging, don't give them the chance to approach you.

This is quite class-agnostic. There might be a better option based on your character class AND skills.